# Excel VBA script: Crash on End If

Tags: excel, vba

> **Details:**
>   *In this segment, I am filling the cell referenced by 'z' with modified date values from cell referenced by 'a', depending on the conditions met. The code crashes at the inner End If line.*

Code snippet:

```
    If Range(x).Value =1 Then
        If Day(Range(a)) > Day(Range(b)) Then
           Range(z).Value = DateSerial(Year(Range(a)), Month(Range(a)), Day(Range(a)-1)) + TimeSerial(20,0,0)
        Else
           Range(z).Value = DateSerial(Year(Range(a)), Month(Range(a)), Day(Range(a))) + TimeSerial(20,0,0)
        End If
    ElseIf Range(y).Value =1 Then
        Range(z).Value = DateSerial(Year(Range(a)), Month(Range(a)), Day(Range(a)-1)) + TimeSerial(8,0,0)
    Else
        Range(z).Value = Range(a).Value
    End If
```

Comment: Your comments to Dan's answer sounds much more like an endless loop to me - is there any looping around the code provided?

Comment: something else must be going on in the background that is confusing the compiler

Comment: Hi whytheq, I step through the code a step at a time, it doesn't seem to spend a long time on any one particular line of code. I can't be sure. I must mention the number of rows is 13500. But again why slow from one day to the next? Could it be my machine, lenovo x61?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good.  Either you have a problem where one of your ranges is pointing to invalid data, or you have corruption in your module.

You can handle corruption by exporting your moodules to a text file (right click module in VBA editor->export) and then import into a clean workbook.

Comment: By crashes do you mean that it does not produce a VBA error message, it just crashes Excel altogether?

Comment: I did not save the scripts in the workbook. I copy paste to the macro editor to run it fresh everytime. I notice the cell where it stops is not the same everytime. I have also checked the cell references in the code. They are correct.

Comment: By crashes I mean it hangs. I 'esc' it, to go to the debugger, where a yellow arrow points to the line of code where the problem has occured. It does populate a range of cells in the destination column.

Comment: Is it possible your simplified code above is hiding the true problem?  Can you show your actual code?  Is this running in some kind of loop which might accidentally be of the infinite variety?

Comment: I have belatedly realized that the script doesn't crash. It runs very slowly. I don't know what caused this suddenly, but it takes close to 10 minutes to complete, the same thing took less than a minute yesterday.

Comment: Thank you Dan Metheus for your response.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to test fine for me.

I know default properties have been created in order to make code more concise, and I realize objects should not *need* to be fully qualified with their parent objects but I don't always trust the `VBA` compiler so my version is a little longer than yours (I've used the cells `C1` to `C5` to test):

```
Option Explicit

Sub FullyQualified()

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If .Range("C1").Value = 1 Then
        If Day(.Range("C3").Value) > Day(.Range("C4").Value) Then
           .Range("C5").Value = DateSerial(Year(.Range("C3").Value), Month(.Range("C3").Value), Day(.Range("C3").Value - 1)) + TimeSerial(20, 0, 0)
        Else
           .Range("C5").Value = DateSerial(Year(.Range("C3").Value), Month(.Range("C3").Value), Day(.Range("C3").Value)) + TimeSerial(20, 0, 0)
        End If
    ElseIf .Range("C2").Value = 1 Then
        .Range("C5").Value = DateSerial(Year(.Range("C3").Value), Month(.Range("C3").Value), Day(.Range("C3").Value - 1)) + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
    Else
        .Range("C5").Value = .Range("C3").Value
    End If
End With

End Sub
```